# Android resource compilation failed error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/visibility' with config ''

Tags: android

I updated library from

```
androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2
 to
androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3
```

and I sync the project now I am getting error in values.xml with below, I don't know where I did wrong, error is `Android resource compilation failed
 error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/visibility' with config ''. and error: resource previously defined here.`

```
  <declare-styleable name="PropertySet"><attr name="visibility">
                <enum name="visible" value="0"/>
                <enum name="invisible" value="1"/>
                <enum name="gone" value="2"/>
            </attr><attr format="float" name="alpha"/><attr name="progress"/></declare-styleable>
```

Comment: it there attr file in value folder?

Comment: where? \app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3237:

Comment: res/values/attr.xml

Comment: no, it is not there

Comment: then remove this <enum name="invisible" value="1"/> or all PropertySet .

Comment: why I need to remove only <enum name="invisible" value="1"/> or all PropertySet

Comment: you have already defined already

Comment: only Solution is downgrade to 2.0.0-alpha2 , I reported this bug to google before. @devha puts the link in answer

Comment: I am using 2.0.0-alpha2  only , but I tested with alpha 3

Comment: i was also facing the same issue. i just changed <attr name="visibility"> to <attr name="myvisibility">. But sometimes it will make a build and sometimes it fails.

Answer (score 3):

This is issue on `constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3`, hopefully it will be fixed on next alpha release: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121395935